# exporting a .csv file from download button

Tags: php, csv, pdo, export-to-excel

EDIT: I changed "echo($row)" to "print_r($row)" and now the csv that's being downloaded has each array in parenthesis with all the data mentioned, but how do I customize the way it all can be printed?

Right now, it's printing:

Array (
[id]=>1
[firstname]=>"Timmy"
)
Array (
....

(where each line is the next row in the excel spreadsheet)

How would I make this output so that each record has it's own row? for example the first column in excel would be id, then the second would be firstname, with each record it's own row?

I've got a link in my main.php:

```
<a class="btn" href="export.php">Export</a>
```

Then here's my export.php file:

```
<?php

//open database connection
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8',
                    'DBUSER',
                    'DBPASS');

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "did not connect...";
}

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=exported-data.csv');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name;";

$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$filename = date('d.m.Y').'.csv';

$data = fopen($filename, 'w');

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    fputcsv($data, $row);
    print_r($row);
}

echo "\r\n";

fclose($data);

?>
```

Comment: Where do you connect to your database? The error implies that your database username/password is incorrect and it can't connect - this issue is *not* with the CSV delivery.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions - they are **officially deprecated**. You should move over to `mysqli_*` or PDO prepared statements.

Comment: @benPearlKahan can you please reply with the correct way to actually do these PDO prepared statements?

Comment: It's always just a Google away.... [Here's the PHP.net official page, with examples](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @benPearlKahan So the best way to probably go about this is to make a stored procedure that will prepare an excel spreadsheet and then call this procedure with PDO format?

Comment: Using PDO, [is really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: @NoReceipt4Panda - PDO has nothing to do with the `CSV` format, or *Excel* spreadsheets. PDO is a way to communicate with a database. Your current code is not only incomplete, it's defunct and the functions are no longer supported by `PHP`. Use PDO prepared statements as @JayBlanchard said to get the data, then use your current code to output the data as a `CSV` file. Simples!

Comment: @BenPearlKahan if I get the PDO code to this question here in the next 5 minutes, can you tell me what I can do to get it working?

Comment: @BenPearlKahan I just changed the code to PDO format, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I just changed the code to PDO format, can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to get this working?

Comment: the syntax here is bad: `$filename = '.date('d.m.Y').'.csv';`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You're using `$db` to connect, but `$conn` to try to run the query. Those must match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101605/discussion-between-noreceipt4panda-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I am not able to chat from this location @NoReceipt4Panda

Comment: @JayBlanchard that's fine. I just changed the $conn to $db, now when I click my link, it takes me to URL....export.php, but does not prompt a downloadable file nor display any information

Comment: You're not echoing out any information to be seen if the code above is all you have.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I just placed "echo $row;" inside of the while loop, but it just spits out "arrayarrayarrayarray" with no download prompt of cvs file. Any idea how to solve so that info comes out as actual field names? and so that it prompts a download?

Comment: Each `$row` is an array. You do not have any code which prompts for a download. You will have to a.) write to a file and 2.) provide a link to the file OR iii.) force download of the file.

Comment: @JayBlanchard what would be the proper "call" to write the fields to the file? say for example each record has these fields: "id" and "firstname"

Comment: Actually I missed that you're doing `fopen()` and `fputscsv()`. Is the file being written?

Comment: @JayBlanchard not that I can see. all that's happening is a redirect to export.php with "arrayarrayarrayarray" as the output on the actual page

Comment: If the file is not being written check the error logs.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, I just figured out how to download the file, but can you please help me figure out how to go about making the correct echo statement for all the fields to output?

Comment: The `fputscsv()` should do that. Each row is an array that should be parsed by that function, with commas, and inserted into the file. Is the file empty?

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's not putting the data in, only a string matching the number of records to the number of repeated "array" words. I have 5 records, each with an id and firstname fields, what I actually get is "arrayarrayarrayarrayarray"

Comment: For a test add `print_r($row);` to your loop and share the output of that.

Comment: @JayBlanchard ah yes, getting closer now... now it's spitting out Array ( [id]=>4 [firstname]=>Timmy ) ArrayArray (........

Comment: @JayBlanchard Is there a way to make it friendlier? for example have it not print Array each time? maybe print each entity on it's own row?

Comment: I'll have something for you in a sec. I'll add an answer.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you. I don't know if you know exactly how it can be done, but with each record on it's own row, each field for that record be it's own column. so I guess, if you were looking at an excel spreadsheet, the first row would be Timmy's row, with the first column containing his id, the second, containing his name (another field) and so on..

Comment: The answer I wrote, which is too long for comments, goes hand-in-hand with everything else that we have discussed and will write one record per row regardless of how may columns are in the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get an associative array to be placed properly into your file you'll need to parse the array and then put the line in the file:

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $csv = implode(',', $row) . "\n";
    fwrite($data, $csv);
    print_r($csv);
}
```

Comment: fwrite doesn't actually put anything into the file being downloaded. I just tried this code instead of what is mentioned in my edited post and I downloaded a blank file

Comment: Are there any errors? If we're not writing to the file, there must be an error.

Comment: I just edited your post, I put in the print_r line and everything has now printed to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmmmm, that doesn't make too much sense. `print_r()` is echoing the array data, but shouldn't be writing it anywhere.

Comment: Without the print_r statement, I was downloading an excel sheet that was completely blank. with the statement, all the data is now showing in the exact format you suggested with your code.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your output should be a csv file with the date as a file name, am I correct?

Could you try this:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<?php

//open database connection
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME;charset=utf8',
                    'DBUSER',
                    'DBPASS');

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}
catch(PDOException $ex) {
    echo "did not connect...";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";

$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$filename = date('d.m.Y').'.csv';

$data = fopen($filename, 'w');

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    fputcsv($data, $row);
}

fclose($data);


?>
```

The code will break because the "." is in the wrong place.

**`$filename = date('d.m.Y').'.csv';`** is not the same as **`$filename = 'date('d.m.Y').'.csv';`**

@NoReceipt4Panda: I can not comment so Code is updated. 
You should be using **`$sth = $db->prepare($sql);` not `$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);`.** 
You don't have a variable with the name `$conn`.

Comment: I just tried this.. but it breaks on this line: $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);

Comment: to be specific, error is this: "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object"

Comment: That error means that you have a problem with your query @NoReceipt4Panda

Comment: @MDChaara, I just changed it to db instead of conn, and it's redirecting me to URL....export.php but not prompting and download files nor displaying any info..